# how can I assign color to different groups in box plot

Tags: r

I have a data like this

```
df<- structure(list(Samples = structure(c(1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
    9L, 10L, 11L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 2L, 
    3L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 
    6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
    10L, 11L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 2L, 3L, 
    1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
    7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
    11L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
    4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
    8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("Sam1", "Sam10", "Sam11", 
    "Sam2", "Sam3", "Sam4", "Sam5", "Sam6", "Sam7", "Sam8", "Sam9"
    ), class = "factor"), variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
    8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
    11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
    12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L), .Label = c("Group1", "Group1", 
    "Group1", "Group2", "Group2", "Group2", "Group3", "Group3", "Group3", 
    "Group4", "Group4", "Group4"), class = "factor"), value = c(0.000708, 
    0.000525, 0.0026, 5.5e-05, 0.000291, 0.00177, 0.000281, 0.00117, 
    0.000199, 0.0133, 0.00161, 0.000708, 0.000525, 0.0026, 5.5e-05, 
    0.000291, 0.00177, 0.000281, 0.00117, 0.000199, 0.0133, 0.00161, 
    0.000708, 0.000525, 0.0026, 5.5e-05, 0.000291, 0.00177, 0.000281, 
    0.00117, 0.000199, 0.0133, 0.00161, 0.000777, 0.00177, 0.00175, 
    4.47e-05, 0.000131, 0.000834, 3e-04, 0.0019, 0.000164, 0.0115, 
    0.00109, 0.000777, 0.00177, 0.00175, 4.47e-05, 0.000131, 0.000834, 
    3e-04, 0.0019, 0.000164, 0.0115, 0.00109, 0.000777, 0.00177, 
    0.00175, 4.47e-05, 0.000131, 0.000834, 3e-04, 0.0019, 0.000164, 
    0.0115, 0.00109, 0.000398, 0.000738, 0.00224, 5.28e-05, 0.000243, 
    0.000783, 0.000284, 0.00153, 0.000191, 0.0141, 0.00124, 0.000398, 
    0.000738, 0.00224, 5.28e-05, 0.000243, 0.000783, 0.000284, 0.00153, 
    0.000191, 0.0141, 0.00124, 0.000398, 0.000738, 0.00224, 5.28e-05, 
    0.000243, 0.000783, 0.000284, 0.00153, 0.000191, 0.0141, 0.00124, 
    0.00237, 0.000661, 0.00364, 4.44e-05, 0.000238, 0.000925, 0.000395, 
    0.00588, 1e-04, 0.0141, 0.00147, 0.00237, 0.000661, 0.00364, 
    4.44e-05, 0.000238, 0.000925, 0.000395, 0.00588, 1e-04, 0.0141, 
    0.00147, 0.00237, 0.000661, 0.00364, 4.44e-05, 0.000238, 0.000925, 
    0.000395, 0.00588, 1e-04, 0.0141, 0.00147)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -132L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am trying to plot it like this

```
cols <- rainbow_hcl(4, c = 50)  # choose chromaticity of 50 to dull colours
ggplot(data = df, aes(x=variable, y=value),col=cols) + 
  stat_boxplot(geom="errorbar", width=.5)+
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=variable))+
  theme(legend.position="none")+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(), axis.title.y=element_blank())+
  stat_summary(fun.y=median, colour="red", geom="line", aes(group = 1))+
  geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(0.2))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's something weird about your data frame, it has duplicated levels:

```
levels(df$variable)
 [1] "Group1" "Group1" "Group1" "Group2" "Group2" "Group2" "Group3" "Group3"
 [9] "Group3" "Group4" "Group4" "Group4"
```

We sort that out first:

```
df$variable=factor(as.character(df$variable))
```

Then we plot:

```
cols <- rainbow_hcl(4, c = 50)  # choose chromaticity of 50 to dull colours
g <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x=variable, y=value,col=variable)) + 
  stat_boxplot(geom="errorbar", width=.5)+
  geom_boxplot()+
  theme(legend.position="none")+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(), axis.title.y=element_blank())+
  stat_summary(fun.y=median, colour="red", geom="line", aes(group = 1))+
  geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(0.2))

g + scale_fill_manual(values=cols)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to assign the color parameter inside of the `aes` function. Additionally, you'll need to include a `scale_color_manual` layer to use the specific color vector you have (e.g. `cols`).

How does this look?

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x=variable, y=value, color = variable)) + 
  stat_boxplot(geom="errorbar", width=.5)+
  geom_boxplot()+
  scale_color_manual(values = cols) +
  theme(legend.position="none")+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(), axis.title.y=element_blank())+
  stat_summary(fun.y=median, colour="red", geom="line", aes(group = 1))+
  geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(0.2))
```